# Add opacity to overflow in slider

Tags: css, drupal-7, slider, jquery-cycle

I have an slider in my home page. All works fine, but I'm trying to do an overflow with an opacity in 0.4 for example. I'm using jQuery cycle in a Drupal 7. This is the code I am using.

```
  $('.view-slider-sports .view-content').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollLeft',
    speed:  'slow',
    timeout: 5000,
    next:   '.next2',
    prev:   '.prev2',
    delay: -1000,
  });
```

The idea is to have the images displaying on the side of the "principal image". Normally, I have this 'other images' using `overflow:hidden`.

How can I display all the images but only apply the opacity to the images in the side of the slider?

Comment: Without further info I would suggest using some element placed where the images should have opacity, set this elements `z-index` to a higher value and give it a transparent background. Wouldn't that do the job?

Comment: Yes I was thinking on doing that, but I was not really shure if it was a good solution. I'll try this, thank you!